# I need help using the 'at' command

Tags: linux

Hello guys I just started to use Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server, I'm stuck using the at command.
Don't know how to initiate the command. This is what I'm trying do to:

I'm trying to run this file at 5 AM using the 'at" command
/etc/holler.sh

Thank You In Advance!

Comment: Run the file /etc/holler.sh

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with `at` -

1) Install `at`

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

2) Schedule your command

```
at 05:00 /somePathTo/someCommand
```

Comment: Is it like a cron? :O

Comment: @jakon It's similar, `man at` - "at      executes commands at a specified time."

Comment: @user3503915 if the proposed answer worked for you kindly set the answer as the accepted answer so that others would find it helpful.